# Using truetone with external monitor in clamshell mode

Tags: display

I have MBP 2019 that I want to use in clamshell mode with an external display.
But I'd like to be able to use true tone.

Now, I am aware that it needs sensors in the Macbook.

I've been thinking more in line of:

1. Open macbook pro, let true tone adjust color.
2. Run some terminal command to 'freeze' the settings.
3. Close the lid.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Well I couldn't find a terminal command line, but what I did was,

1. Turn off True Tone altogether.
2. set a custom nightshift mode that matches the warmth of the display with true-tone for 24 hours.[image: Screenshot of my setting]